# Find a prime number $p$ and an integer $b<p$ such that $p$ divides $b^{p−1}−1$.

Tags: prime-numbers

Find a prime number $p$ and an integer $b<p$ such that $p$ divides $b^{p−1}−1$.

First I think of long divisions but it didn't work out. Now I'm stuck..

Comment: Fermat's little theorem tells us any prime $p$ and any integer $0<b<p$ works

Comment: For **any** non zero $\;b\;$ and **any** prime $\;p\;,\;\;0<b<p\;$ , that will work. Try it!

Comment: guys I don't get it..

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem

Comment: @YujunPan Try random numbers, see what works. $p=3,b=2$ works (because $3$ divides $2^{3-1}-1=3$), as does $p=5$ and $b=3$ (because $5$ divides $3^{5-1}-1=80$). What Sayan and Timbuc are saying, is that _any_ $b$ and $p$ work.

Answer (score 1):

Hint; You can Make $p=3$ and $b=2$.